# How can you link different node/points and display the path in flutter?Like in the picture below

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

I would like to make points or nodes that can be connected using a path that is visible .Like in word connect .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.